# Problem with passing parameter and recieving paramenter in javascript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using a Action link button my project and using a Javascript function as well.
which is updating my 2 partial view but when I run  my project It gives me an error.

The name 'temp' does not exist in the current context

```
              <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "Employee", new { Id = Employee.EmployeeID }, newAjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Employee",HttpMethod="Post", OnSuccess = "EmployeeHistory('" + Employee.EmployeeID.ToString() + "')" })%>
```

and 
let the javascript function I m calling is as

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function EmployeeHistory(EmployeeID) {
       $('#EmployeeInformation').load('<%= Url.Action("EmployeeInformation", "Home",new { Id=EmployeeID}) %>');
       }

       function success(result){
       $("#EmployeeInformation").html(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix server side code with javascript like this (`Url.Action` runs on the server while `EmployeeID` is a javascript variable):

```
$('#EmployeeInformation').load('<%= Url.Action("EmployeeInformation", "Home",new { Id=EmployeeID}) %>');
```

Try the following:

```
var url = '<%= Url.Action("EmployeeInformation", "Home") %>';
$('#EmployeeInformation').load(url, { id: EmployeeID }));
```

Also you need to define the `OnSuccess` like this:

```
OnSuccess = "function() { EmployeeHistory('" + Employee.EmployeeID.ToString() + "'); }"
```

But quite quite honestly I would use jQuery with a standard `Html.ActionLink` helper and do things unobtrusively:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Select", 
    "Employee", 
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = Employee.EmployeeID }),
    new Dictionary<string, object> { 
        { "id", "selectEmployee" }, 
        { "data-id", Employee.EmployeeID } 
    }
) %>
```

and then I would unobtrusively AJAXify it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#selectEmployee').click(function() {
            var link = $(this);
            $.post(this.href, function(result) {
                $('#Employee').html(result);
                var url = '<%= Url.Action("EmployeeInformation", "Home") %>';
                $('#EmployeeInformation').load(url, { id: link.data('id') });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i think he is expecting employeeid from signature of js function EmployeeHistory(EmployeeID) and having problem in passing this param through ajax options